# Operand should contain 1 column - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert records from one table to another.  But it is giving me following error

**Operand should contain 1 column**

I am running this command

```
           INSERT INTO categories (`user_id`,`system_category_id`,`category_name`,
    `bookmark_count`,
     `category_type`, `approval_status`,`category_create_date`,
    `last_updated`)  
        SELECT (`user_id`,`system_category_id`,`category_name`,
    `bookmark_count`, `category_type`, `approval_status`,
`category_create_date`,
 `last_updated`)
    FROM tmp
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove the parentheses after SELECT. That is:

```
INSERT INTO categories (`user_id`,`system_category_id`,`category_name`,
`bookmark_count`,`category_type`, `approval_status`,`category_create_date`,
`last_updated`)  
SELECT `user_id`,`system_category_id`,`category_name`,
`bookmark_count`, `category_type`, `approval_status`,`category_create_date`,
`last_updated`
FROM tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without function braces around select query I have try with same query and its working:

```
INSERT INTO categories (`user_id`,`system_category_id`,`category_name`,
`bookmark_count`,`category_type`, `approval_status`,`category_create_date`,
`last_updated`)  
SELECT `user_id`,`system_category_id`,`category_name`,
`bookmark_count`, `category_type`, `approval_status`,`category_create_date`,
`last_updated`
FROM tmp
```